# Setting type on useLocation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to add typescript to my project, however i am getting this error for uselocation in the IDE. Any idea what i am doing wrong ?

```
import React from "react";
import { useHistory, useLocation, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import {ILocation} from '../Interfaces'
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import "../App.css";
const Rocket = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  const location = useLocation<ILocation>();
  const rocketData = location?.data?.rocketDetails;
```

and then this is my Interface

```
import { rootReducer } from "./redux/configureStore";

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>


export interface ILocation {
    data: Object
}
```

Error i get in iDE is this - Property 'data' does not exist on type 'Location'.ts(2339)

Data that is passed to the component onCLick is this

```
<Button
          onClick={() => {
            history.push({
              pathname: `/user/${userData.id}`,
              data: { userDetails: userData },
            });
          }}
        >
          Click here for details
        </Button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location), that's not how you declare custom state.

Instead, pass state as the second argument.

```
history.push(`/user/${userData.id}`, { data: { userDetails: userData } });
```

That data will now appear on the `state` property of the location:

```
const location = useLocation<{ data: { userDetails: MyUserDetailsType } }>()
location.state.data.userDetails // the data you want.
```

Comment: Did work! I realised i was not using the data as you did on the last line, where you pulled the data from location.state. Thanks for this!